# To run Specific ANT Command from Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ant

I have created a JSP which takes some local file resources and server details enter by user and then passes all these details to the Servlet which creates some properties files in the ant folder by the user entered server details and also copies the resource to the ant folder.(both client and server are on the same machine).

The ant command to execute is

```
ant -DTIBCO-HOME=D:\Tibco_homeFiles -Dconfig.file=Apps/create.properties
```

When i run from Command Prompt it works fine, I wanted to know how to create and execute an ant project in the servlet with the above command to run.

Comment: Have a look at how to invoke ant programmatically in this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html (you'd still need to figure out where your build script is, etc.)

Comment: This article is related to your question => http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/07/24/antauto.html